# Losing sound quality from CD (phono) to mixer (jack)

Tags: stereo, mixer

Can anyone help? I am trying to run my CD/DVD player through my 4-way mixer, so have plugged phono leads out from CD, into the jack (via a small-to-large adapter) on the mixer. I lose massive sound quality (especially vocal tracks) from the CD. Yet if I unplug one of the phono leads, I get it back (but only in mono). I've tried switching leads, jack adapter, mixer input socket, etc, and the only thing I can do is keep one of the phono leads unplugged (in "CD audio out").

Any explanations / fixes?

Comment: what is your mixer model

Answer (score 1):

The wiring of the plug to the adapter is wrong. The loss of sound quality you are hearing is basically because you are listening to L-R in mono which will negate the centre-panned vocals.

You need to use a different input and different connection strategy. you need to change all connection components in order to eliminate the issue. Try a different set of leads, jack adapter etc.Also make sure that the jack plug is firmly seated in the adapter - sounds like it might not be at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run each channel of the CD player to a separate input on the mixer. Your "4-way mixer" most likely has mono channels, so to properly handle the CD player output you need to use two mixer channels or use a mixer with a stereo input.